# Opencv Camera crashes with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera

Here is the code for my live camera in opencv.

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    # Display the resulting frame

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (0,0,int(frame.shape[0]/3),frame.shape[1]),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(frame.shape[0]),0,int(frame.shape[0]*(1/3)),frame.shape[1]),(0,0,255),2)
    #
    # leftPortion = frame[:,0:int(frame.shape[0]/3),:]
    # rightPortion = frame[:,int(frame.shape[0]*(3/3)):,:]

    # BOXES = detect_hands(frame,graph,sess)
    # boxes = predict(BOXES,frame.shape[0],frame.shape[1])
    #
    # x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = boxes[0]
    # x = int((x_min + x_max) / 2)
    # y = int((y_min + y_max) / 2)
    # cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 5, (255,0,0), -1)
    # if len(boxes) == 1:
    #     x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = boxes[0]
    #     x = int((x_min + x_max) / 2)
    #     y = int((y_min + y_max) / 2)
    #     cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 20, (255,0,0), -1)
    cv2.imshow('window',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is, it runs good. Quite good, but after certain time, (not exactly the same every time), the camera crashes with the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). No errors, nothing. I don't even remember tweaking any settings, apart from one regedit setting when camera was failed to be detected by the laptop, but later I reverted whatever I did. Any solution for this problem  please?

Answer (score 1):

if you are running it on the Raspberry Pi, it crashes when the memory is full and you have to reload it in order to bypass this error

Comment: Running on a laptop. 1060 GTX NVIDIA, 16 GB RAM.

Comment: Are you running it in a jupyter notebook?